# Why is react not displaying "hello" or "goodbye" messages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This creates a page with a single button.  The button has 2 options. I would like it to return either "hello world" or "goodbye world" when pressed.  But it doesn't work.  I cannot get the "hello" or "goodbye" messages to display on invocation.

Here is what the screen looks like when calling the menu items:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
import './App.css'

import {Amplify} from 'aws-amplify';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import awsExports from './aws-exports';
import {Menu, MenuItem, MenuButton, Flex} from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);

function App() {
    function displayHello() {
        console.log("Loaded basic!")
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>
    }

    function displayGoodbye() {
        console.log("Loaded goodbye!")
        return <h1>Goodbye World</h1>
    }

    return (
        <Menu
            trigger={
                <MenuButton
                    variation="primary"
                    size="large"
                    width="20%">
                    Salutation
                </MenuButton>
            }
        >
            <MenuItem onClick={displayHello}>Hello</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={displayGoodbye}>Goodbye</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Returning something from an onClick function doesn't do anything.

Comment: And give https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory a read-through. As well as literally the rest of the "Learn React" docs. They're excellent, and taking the time to read them now will save you exponentially more time in the future trying to debug things that the tutorials teach you how to do properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onClick binds a function to an event just like [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) would do, therefore returning [JSX](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) in it doesn't make any sense.

**Possible Solution**

```
const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState(<h1>Good Morning World</h1>);

const setDisplayHello = () => {
   setDisplayValue(<h1>Hello World</h1>);
}

return (
   <div onClick={setDisplayHello}>
     {displayValue}
   </div>
)
```

You could do it this way but I wouldn't store JSX  in a react state, you can just store a string instead like:

```
const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState('Good Morning World');

const setDisplayHello = () => {
   setDisplayValue('Hello World');
}

return (
   <div onClick={setDisplayHello}>
     <h1>{displayValue}</h1>
   </div>
)
```